# jquery multiselect filter cannot be reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery UI multiselect plugin, and i want to reload the multiselect with filter in it.

i tried this:

```
$("#select").multiselect("destroy").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
```

but this only reloads a new multiselect whithout any filter in it. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen sample?

Answer (score 0):

i would not recommend the destroy option here instead you can use

```
$("#select").multiSelect('refresh');
```